# How to write an efficient groupBy-size filter in Scala, can be approximate

Tags: scala, group-by, bloom-filter, foldleft

Given a `List[Int]` in Scala, I wish to get the `Set[Int]` of all `Int`s which appear at least `thresh` times. I can do this using `groupBy` or `foldLeft`, then `filter`. For example:

```
val thresh = 3
val myList = List(1,2,3,2,1,4,3,2,1)
myList.foldLeft(Map[Int,Int]()){case(m, i) => m + (i -> (m.getOrElse(i, 0) + 1))}.filter(_._2 >= thresh).keys
```

will give `Set(1,2)`.

Now suppose the `List[Int]` is very large. How large it's hard to say but in any case this seems wasteful as I don't care about each of the `Int`s frequencies, and I only care if they're at least `thresh`. Once it passed `thresh` there's no need to check anymore, just add the `Int` to the `Set[Int]`.

The question is: can I do this more efficiently for a very large `List[Int]`,

a) if I need a true, accurate result (no room for mistakes)

b) if the result can be approximate, e.g. by using some Hashing trick or Bloom Filters, where `Set[Int]` might include some false-positives, or whether {the frequency of an `Int` > `thresh`} isn't really a `Boolean` but a `Double` in `[0-1]`.

Comment: What about passing also an array to fold with the final results, so inside fold after you add to the map you check the count and if it's greater than thresh add it to the array. Then you don't need to call filter after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't do better than O(N), as you need to check each element of your initial array at least once. You current approach is O(N), presuming that operations with `IntMap` are effectively constant.

Now what you can try in order to increase efficiency:

- update map only when current counter value is less or equal to threshold. This will eliminate huge number of most expensive operations — map updates
- try faster map instead of IntMap. If you know that values of the initial List are in fixed range, you can use `Array` instead of `IntMap` (index as the key). Another possible option will be mutable `HashMap` with sufficient initail capacity. As my benchmark shows it actually makes significant difference
- As @ixx proposed, after incrementing value in the map, check whether it's equal to 3 and in this case add it immediately to result list. This will save you one linear traversing (appears to be not that significant for large input)

I don't see how any approximate solution can be faster (only if you ignore some elements at random). Otherwise it will still be O(N).

**Update**

I created microbenchmark to measure the actual performance of different implementations. For sufficiently large input and output Ixx's suggestion regarding immediately adding elements to result list doesn't produce significant improvement. However similar approach could be used to eliminate unnecessary Map updates (which appears to be the most expensive operation).

Results of benchmarks (avg run times on 1000000 elems with pre-warming):

```
Authors solution:
447 ms
Ixx solution:
412 ms
Ixx solution2 (eliminated excessive map writes):
150 ms
My solution:
57 ms
```

My solution involves using mutable `HashMap` instead of immutable `IntMap` and includes all other possible optimizations.

**Ixx's updated solution:**

```
val tuple = (Map[Int, Int](), List[Int]())
val res = myList.foldLeft(tuple) {
  case ((m, s), i) =>
    val count = m.getOrElse(i, 0) + 1
    (if (count <= 3) m + (i -> count) else m, if (count == thresh) i :: s else s)
}
```

**My solution:**

```
val map = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]()
val res = new ListBuffer[Int]
myList.foreach {
  i =>
    val c = map.getOrElse(i, 0) + 1
    if (c == thresh) {
      res += i
    }
    if (c <= thresh) {
      map(i) = c
    }
}
```

The full microbenchmark source is available [here](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/1364baae6fbdcb812f5b).

Comment: Thank you @Aivean, this was very inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `foldleft` to collect the matching items, like this:

```
val tuple = (Map[Int,Int](), List[Int]())
myList.foldLeft(tuple) {
  case((m, s), i) => {
    val count = (m.getOrElse(i, 0) + 1) 
    (m + (i -> count), if (count == thresh) i :: s else s)
  }
}
```

I could measure a performance improvement of about 40% with a small list, so it's definitely an improvement...

Edited to use `List` and prepend, which takes constant time (see comments).

Comment: Good point, but actually using a `Set` as the result collector is not as good as using any other collection with constant append time (or `List` for prepend). You are adding element to the result collection every time when `count >= thresh`, which is unnecessary. It is sufficient to add it exactly once, when `count == thresh`, as well it is faster.

Comment: Oh, that's correct - I missed that. I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, default implementation of `Seq` is `List`. So right now you are appending to it, which takes linear time (much worse than effective constant of appending to `Set`). Try `List[Int]` instead and prepend it instead of appending: `i :: s`.

Comment: I'm not seeing a significant performance improvement, but I'm also testing with a relatively small dataset and not optimal testing conditions... I'll edit the answer anyway.

Comment: True, it's because you don't have sufficient elements in `s`. I just created the benchmark where `s` contains 10000 elements in the end. The difference in performance between appending to `Seq` (which is `List` as I said) and prepending to `List` was **4 times** (2000+ ms vs 400+ ms).

Answer (score 1):

If by "more efficiently" you mean the space efficiency (in extreme case when the list is infinite), there's a probabilistic data structure called [Count Min Sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch) to estimate the frequency of items inside it. Then you can discard those with frequency below your threshold.

There's a Scala implementation from [Algebird](http://twitter.github.io/algebird/index.html#com.twitter.algebird.CMS) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `foldLeft` example a bit using  a  `mutable.Set` that is build incrementally and at the same time used as filter for iterating over your `Seq` by using `withFilter`. However, because I'm using `withFilter`i cannot use `foldLeft` and have to make do with `foreach` and a mutable map:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def getItems[A](in: Seq[A], threshold: Int): Set[A] = {
  val counts: mutable.Map[A, Int] = mutable.Map.empty
  val result: mutable.Set[A] = mutable.Set.empty

  in.withFilter(!result(_)).foreach { x =>
    counts.update(x, counts.getOrElse(x, 0) + 1)

    if (counts(x) >= threshold) {          
      result += x
    }
  }
  result.toSet
}
```

So, this would discard items that have already been added to the result set while running through the `Seq` the first time, because `withFilter`filters the `Seq`in the appended function (`map, flatMap, foreach`) rather than returning a filtered `Seq`.

**EDIT:**

I changed my solution to not use `Seq.count`, which was stupid, as *Aivean* correctly pointed out.

Using *Aiveans* microbench I can see that it is still slightly slower than his approach, but still better than the authors first approach.

```
Authors solution
377
Ixx solution: 
399
Ixx solution2 (eliminated excessive map writes): 
110
Sascha Kolbergs solution: 
72
Aivean solution: 
54
```

Comment: This is **very** bad approach. Operation `in.count(_ == x)` is performed in linear time, so your solution is O(N^2), which is way worse that original author's solution.

Comment: @Aivean ah, true, that's probably what felt wrong, edited my answer.